# options.fetch . I don't get it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Look at the discussion on [this thread](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4558) . I am not able to follow how having a block to a fetch is a better solution.

Comment: Sorry my "to avoid an unnecessary calculation in case the :alt option is specified" was not clear enough :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [first patch](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4558/a/514772/nil-alt-tag.diff) on [Rails ticket #4558](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4558):

```
options.fetch(:alt, File.basename(src, '.*').capitalize)
```

This line executes the basename and capitalize functions and then passes the result into `Hash#fetch` regardless of if a value for :alt already exists in the options hash.

In the [updated patch](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4558/a/514874/nil-alt-tag-2.diff):

```
options.fetch(:alt) { File.basename(src, '.*').capitalize }
```

The same basename/capitalize code is only executed when `Hash#fetch` needs the default value (i.e. when the :alt key does not exist in the options hash). This means the (possibly expensive) calculation of the default value can be skipped if it's not needed.

See the documentation on [`Hash#fetch`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M002849) for more details.

Comment: I thought that was the case but I guess my test was not a good one. Since the result was same in both the cases and thus I got confused. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what duck-punching Rails has been doing to `Hash#fetch`, but with Plain Old Ruby Objects, I use it rather than `Hash#[]` because when I ask for something and it's not available, I want to know about it. This is called "Failing early" (or "Crashing early" in *The Pragmatic Programmer's* [List of Tips](http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips))