# How to Check if every varaible in a Java class contain Null?

Tags: java, null

I have Set which contain different type of classes like `Class A` ,`Class B`,`Class C` now one class Let us suppose class A have this structure

```
class A{

String id;
String name;
String password;
 get()/Set() methods 
}
```

Now Let us suppose Class A each variable contain Null . 
How to check If class  variables contain null so i will not process this class its all DB operation.

Any idea how to separate those classes which all variables are null ?

Comment: So you just asked for an if condition ??

Comment: search in google/[SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795455/java-how-to-check-for-null-pointers-efficiently). There are many good practices

Comment: One variable at a time.

Comment: @Zencv i know What Stackoverflow if you can find answer of this question in Google let me know

Answer (score 1):

Just define a method `isClassEligibleForDBOperations()` which returns boolean value and implement it like this.

```
public boolean isClassEligibleForDBOperations()
{
      if(id != null && name != null && password != null)
      {
            return true;
      }
      return false;
}
```

Based on the return type you can implement your logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with JEE6, you can use NOT NULL annotation javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.
Otherwise you can implement your own NOT NULL annotation and use it.

Comment: I am using Java7 any example you have about javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any constructor in these classes? As I don't see any and you are asking for class variables I'd guess its static variable. Than you can check really easy:

```
if(A.variable == null){ 
  // your functions
}
```

or

```
@class A
String getVariable(){
  return variable;
}

@anywhere
if(A.getVariable() == null){ 
  // your functions
}
```

And I hope "variable contains Null" means it's content is null