# What is the difference between require() and library()?

Tags: r, package, r-faq

What is the difference between `require()` and `library()`?

Comment: http://www.mail-archive.com/r-devel@stat.math.ethz.ch/msg00301.html

Comment: Adding a link to @Yihui's blog post unless he wants to post a version of it as an answer. http://yihui.name/en/2014/07/library-vs-require/

Comment: I usually use require if I want a logical value returned after package loading.

Comment: Summarizing @Yihui's blog post: "Ladies and gentlemen, I've said this before: require() is the wrong way to load an R package; use library() instead "

Comment: @DanHall ... because `library()` immediately fails loudly, early, and with a relevant error message (if the package is not installed or could not be loaded), whereas `require()` doesn't raise an error, just silently returns boolean FALSE which gets thrown away, and causes the code to fail later and more cryptically with `Error: object “bar” not found` on (say) line 175.

Comment: Hi @Marco, this question is fairly popular and is getting lots of traffic. Unfortunately the accepted answer is (completely) wrong in that it contradicts commonly accepted best practices, as explained in the comments and by other answers, and is misinforming people. Would you mind considering the other answers and accepting one that provides a correct explanation? (Given that I’m the one supplicating you, I suggest accepting dww’s answer, which I’ve upvoted. It’s the only answer apart from mine that points out the serious caveats of using `require`.)

Answer (score 143, accepted):

In addition to the good advice already given, I would add this:

It is probably best to avoid using `require()` *unless* you actually will be using the value it returns e.g in some error checking loop such as given by thierry.

In most other cases it is better to use `library()`, because this will give an error message at package loading time if the package is not available. `require()` will just fail without an error if the package is not there. This is the best time to find out if the package needs to be installed (or perhaps doesn't even exist because it it spelled wrong).  Getting error feedback early and at the relevant time will avoid possible headaches with tracking down why later code fails when it attempts to use library routines

Answer (score 386):

There's not much of one in everyday work.

However, according to the documentation for both functions (accessed by putting a `?` before the function name and hitting enter), `require` is used inside functions, as it outputs a warning and continues if the package is not found, whereas `library` will throw an error.

Comment: #richiemorrisroe: Thank you. Does it mean that if I load the packages I need at the very beginning of my R-code it does not matter which one I choose?

Comment: as long as you are not loading packages inside a function, it really makes no difference. I load all my packages using require, and didnt know what the difference was until i read the help after seeing your question.

Comment: The other reason I use `require` is that it keeps me from referring to packages as `libraries`, a practice that drives the R-cognoscenti up the wall. The `library` is the directory location where the packages sit.

Comment: They have very relevant differences. Do not use `require`, **unless** you check the return value (and in that case there are usually better alternatives, e.g. `loadNamespace`).

Answer (score 277):

Another benefit of `require()` is that it returns a logical value by default. `TRUE` if the packages is loaded, `FALSE` if it isn't.

```
> test <- library("abc")
Error in library("abc") : there is no package called 'abc'
> test
Error: object 'test' not found
> test <- require("abc")
Loading required package: abc
Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called 'abc'
> test
[1] FALSE
```

So you can use `require()` in constructions like the one below. Which mainly handy if you want to distribute your code to our R installation were packages might not be installed.

```
if(require("lme4")){
    print("lme4 is loaded correctly")
} else {
    print("trying to install lme4")
    install.packages("lme4")
    if(require(lme4)){
        print("lme4 installed and loaded")
    } else {
        stop("could not install lme4")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 93):

## Always use `library`. Never use `require`.

tl;dr: `require` breaks one of the fundamental rules of robust software systems: [**fail early**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2807375/1968).

In a nutshell, this is because, when using `require`, your code might yield different, erroneous results, *without signalling an error*. This is rare but not hypothetical! Consider this code, which *yields different results* depending on whether {dplyr} can be loaded:

```
require(dplyr)

x = data.frame(y = seq(100))
y = 1
filter(x, y == 1)
```

This can lead to subtly wrong results. Using `library` instead of `require` throws an error here, signalling clearly that something is wrong. [This is good](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast_system).

It also makes debugging all other failures more difficult: If you `require` a package at the start of your script and use its exports in line 500, you’ll get an error message “object ‘foo’ not found” in line 500, rather than an error “there is no package called ‘bla’”.

The only acceptable use case of `require` is when its return value is immediately checked, as some of the other answers show. This is a fairly common pattern but even in these cases it is better (and recommended, see below) to instead separate the existence check and the loading of the package. That is: use `requireNamespace` instead of `require` in these cases.

More technically, `require` actually calls `library` internally (if the package wasn’t already attached — `require` thus performs a redundant check, because `library` *also* checks whether the package was already loaded). Here’s a simplified implementation of `require` to illustrate what it does:

```
require = function (package) {
    already_attached = paste('package:', package) %in% search()
    if (already_attached) return(TRUE)
    maybe_error = try(library(package, character.only = TRUE)) 
    success = ! inherits(maybe_error, 'try-error')
    if (! success) cat("Failed")
    success
}
```

---

### Experienced R developers agree:

[Yihui Xie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559676/yihui-xie), author of {knitr}, {bookdown} and many other packages [says](https://yihui.name/en/2014/07/library-vs-require/):

> Ladies and gentlemen, I've said this before: require() is the wrong way to load an R package; use library() instead

[Hadley Wickham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16632/hadley), author of more popular R packages than anybody else, says

> Use `library(x)` in data analysis scripts. […]
> You never need to use `require()` (`requireNamespace()` is almost always better)

Comment: I was gonna point exactly the same, unless you are calling ALL the functions with the syntax `class::function`, use `library()` to avoid precisely that.

Answer (score 77):

You can use `require()` if you want to install packages if and only if necessary, such as:

```
if (!require(package, character.only=T, quietly=T)) {
    install.packages(package)
    library(package, character.only=T)
}
```

For multiple packages you can use

```
for (package in c('<package1>', '<package2>')) {
    if (!require(package, character.only=T, quietly=T)) {
        install.packages(package)
        library(package, character.only=T)
    }
}
```

**Pro tips:**

- When used inside the script, you can avoid a dialog screen by specifying the `repos` parameter of `install.packages()`, such as

  ```
  install.packages(package, repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")
  ```
- You can wrap `require()` and `library()` in `suppressPackageStartupMessages()` to, well, suppress package startup messages, and also use the parameters `require(..., quietly=T, warn.conflicts=F)` if needed to keep the installs quiet.

Answer (score 21):

```
?library
```

and you will see:

> `library(package)` and `require(package)` both load the package with name
>   `package` and put it on the search list. `require` is designed for use
>   inside other functions; it returns `FALSE` and gives a warning (rather
>   than an error as `library()` does by default) if the package does not
>   exist. Both functions check and update the list of currently loaded
>   packages and do not reload a package which is already loaded. (If you
>   want to reload such a package, call `detach(unload = TRUE)` or
>   `unloadNamespace` first.) If you want to load a package without putting
>   it on the search list, use `requireNamespace`.

Answer (score 11):

My initial theory about the difference was that `library` loads the packages whether it is already loaded or not, i.e. it might reload an already loaded package, while `require` just checks that it is loaded, or loads it if it isn't (thus the use in functions that rely on a certain package). The documentation refutes this, however, and explicitly states that neither function will reload an already loaded package.

Comment: this is interesting, but isn't really an answer to the question ... ?

Comment: [This answer is being discussed on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387287/conflict-resolution-for-a-declined-not-an-answer-flag)

Answer (score 5):

Here seems to be the difference on an already loaded package.
While it is true that both require and library do not load the package. Library does a lot of other things before it checks and exits.

I would recommend removing "require" from the beginning of a function running 2mil times anyway, but if, for some reason I needed to keep it. require is technically a faster check.

```
microbenchmark(req = require(microbenchmark), lib = library(microbenchmark),times = 100000)
Unit: microseconds
 expr    min     lq      mean median     uq        max neval
  req  3.676  5.181  6.596968  5.655  6.177   9456.006 1e+05
  lib 17.192 19.887 27.302907 20.852 22.490 255665.881 1e+05
```

Comment: I’d argue that this is a strong reason for fixing the implementation `library` instead (both functions, as currently shipped with R, are a huge mess).

Comment: @KonradRudolph well, if someone is going to fix library, maybe they can also enable loading by version explicitly and make attachment an argument option

Comment: Yes, I absolutely agree but those would change the semantics, not just the performance. Anyway, versioning will never work with packages in R, unfortunately. I’m working on a replacement for this (really!). As for attaching, you can use `loadNamespace`, which loads a package and returns its namespace, without attaching it.