# Legend size in ggplot2 worldmap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the worldmap function from the Maps.R library. It runs in ggplot2.

I would like to make the legend a bit larger. I am using

```
theme(legend.key.size = unit(measure, "units"))
```

My R terminal returns:

```
could not find function "unit"
```

Any clue as to what's going on here?
I believe this to be the correct syntax in ggplot2 to adjust legend size.

Thanks much,
bfb

Comment: Function unit is in library grid. Maybe this library isn't loaded in your session. Try library(grid)

Comment: Very good. Works like a charm. If ggplot2 depends on grid, why didn't R load grid when it loaded ggplot2? Perhaps this gets at another question I've had for a while.. What is the difference between library() and require(), which is best practice to use? Or does it depend? (like most this do)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `unit` is in the `grid` package. You need to explicitly load it and add it to your search path with

```
library("grid")
```

As to your followup question in the comments, since `ggplot2` needs `grid`, `grid` was loaded when `ggplot2` was loaded and its functions were made available to `ggplot2`. However, it was not added to the global search path so its (`grid`'s) functions are not found when you try to call them directly. Calling `library()` (or `require()`) makes them findable.

The difference between the two functions is described in their documentation

> `library(package)` and `require(package)` both load the package with name `package`. `require` is designed for use inside other functions; it returns `FALSE` and gives a warning (rather than an error as `library()` does by default) if the package does not exist.

and in this other question: [What is the difference between require() and library()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5595512/892313)