# Is it a good practice to call functions in a package via ::

Tags: r, scope, namespaces, scoping, qualified-name

I'm writing some R functions that employ some useful functions in other packages like `stringr` and `base64enc`. Is it good not to call `library(...)` or `require(...`) to load these packages first but to use `::` to directly refer to the function I need, like `stringr::str_match(...)`?

Is it a good practice in general case? Or what problem might it induce?

Comment: `require` is generally used within a function in a package and [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595512/what-is-the-difference-between-require-and-library) does a good job distinguishing between it and `library`. If you're sure you're only going to need one (or two) functions from a package, the `::` is fine but I only gravitate towards it when there are namespace collisions. And, don't forget about the `:::` operator, too.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

It all depends on context.

`::` is primarily necessary if there are **namespace collisions**, functions from different packages with the same name. When I load the `dplyr` package, it provides a function `filter`, which collides with (and masks) the `filter` function loaded by default in the `stats` package. So if I want to use the `stats` version of the function after loading `dplyr`, I'll need to call it with `stats::filter`.

This also gives motivation for **not loading lots of packages**. If you really only want one function from a package, it can be better to use `::` than load the whole package, especially if you know the package will mask other functions you want to use.

Not in code, but in text, I do find `::` very useful. It's much more concise to type `stats::filter` than "the `filter` function from the `stats` package".

From a **performance** perspective, there is a (very) small price for using `::`. Long-time R-Core development team member Martin Maechler wrote (on the [r-devel mailing list (Sept 2017)](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2017-September/074850.html))

> Many people seem to forget that every use of `::` is an R
> function call and using it is inefficient compared to just using
> the already imported name.

The performance penalty is **very small**, on the order of a few microseconds, so it's only a concern when you need highly optimized code. Running a line of code that uses `::` one million times will take a second or two longer than code that doesn't use `::`.

As far as portability goes, it's nice to explicitly load packages at the top of a script because it makes it easy to glance at the first few lines and see what packages are needed, installing them if necessary before getting too deep in anything else, i.e., getting halfway through a long process that now can't be completed without starting over.

*Aside*: a similar argument can be made to prefer `library()` over `require()`. Library will cause an error and stop if the package isn't there, whereas require will warn but continue. If your code has a contingency plan in case the package isn't there, then by all means use `if (require(package)) ...`, but if your code will fail without a package you should use `library(package)` at the top so it fails early and clearly.

#### Within your own package

The general solution is to make your own package that `imports` the other packages you need to use in the DESCRIPTION file. Those packages will be automatically installed when your package is installed, so you can use `pkg::fun` internally. Or, by also importing them in the `NAMESPACE` file, you can `import` an entire package or selectively `importFrom` specific functions and not need `::`. Opinions differ on this. Martin Maechler (same r-devel source as above) says:

> Personally I've got the impression that  ::  is
> much "overused" nowadays, notably in packages where I'd strongly
> advocate using  importFrom() in NAMESPACE, so all this happens
> at package load time, and then *not* using `::` in the package
> sources itself.

On the other hand, RStudio Chief Scientist Hadley Wickham says in his [R Packages book](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html):

> It's common for packages to be listed in `Imports` in `DESCRIPTION`, but not in `NAMESPACE`. In fact, this is what I recommend: list the package in `DESCRIPTION` so that it’s installed, then always refer to it explicitly with `pkg::fun()`. Unless there is a strong reason not to, it's better to be explicit.

With two esteemed R experts giving opposite recommendations, I think it's fair to say that you should pick whichever style suits you best and meets your needs for clarity, efficiency, and maintainability.

---

If you frequently find yourself using just one function from another package, you can copy the code and add it to your own package. For example, I have a package for personal use that borrows `%nin%` from the `Hmisc` package because I think it's a great function, but I don't often use anything else from `Hmisc`. With `roxygen2`, it's easy to add `@author` and `@references` to properly attribute the code for a borrowed function. Also make sure the package licenses are compatible when doing this.

Comment: Another advantage to using `library(...)` at the top of your script is that if someone tries to `source` your file without the package installed the `source` command will fail early (and not after potentially long data loads or manipulations).

Comment: `require` is written to return a logical value making it easy to use in the construction: `if( !require(pkg) ){ cat("informative error message")}`

Comment: @BondedDust In a case like that it'd be better to use `stop` or `warning` instead of `cat`.

Comment: If you're writing a package, I think it's better to use `::` rather than namespace imports or importsFrom (unless you're using a _lot_ of functions from the other package)

Comment: @hadley I'll defer to you on this, but I'd like some clarification. If the primary functionality of your package  *needs* `pkg::foo`--even if `foo` is the only function needed from `pkg`---then shouldn't `pkg` be in `Imports` or `Depends` to guarantee that it is installed? If relegated to `Suggests` or `Enhances` then there is no guarantee that `pkg` is there.

Comment: @shujaa Yes, it should be in DESCRIPTION imports, but it shouldn't be in NAMESPACE import(pkg) or importFrom(pkg,foo) (I think my original comment was a bit confusing)

Comment: Short comment on readability of the code might be added. Having each function call prefixed with package name can make the code messy. Especially with some function call being argument of another function call, etc... (common in tidyr)