# R: When to use package::function() vs function()?

Tags: r

I'm learning R, and I can't figure out why sometimes I get "error: could not find function" even after I've installed the package containing that function.

But then it works if I use package::function()

Can someone please explain the difference? Thank you

Comment: You probably forgotten to load the package using `library`. Usually you will use `package::function` when two packages have functions with the same name or when you want to avoid loading a package just for a single function.

Comment: Possible dupe: [Is it a good practice to call functions in a package via ::](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23232791/903061)

Comment: @DavidArenburg  d'oh yes of course... thank you... a little embarrassed right now ....