# How to wait for input widget updates until rendering output in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

See the following nonsense minimal-working example that resembles a problem:

```r
library(shiny)
ui = shiny::fluidPage(

    shiny::sidebarLayout(
        shiny::sidebarPanel(
            shiny::radioButtons("type", "Type", choices = c("5", "15", "21")),
            shiny::sliderInput("x", "x", min = 1, max = 10, value = 7),
            shiny::checkboxInput("auto","Set y to 8 when type is 15, and 9 when type is 21", value = TRUE),
            shiny::sliderInput("y", "y", min = 1, max = 10, value = 7)
        ),

        shiny::mainPanel(
            shiny::plotOutput("show")
        )
    )
)
server = function(input, output, session) {
    plotData = shiny::reactive({
        list(x = input$x, y = input$y, type = input$type)
    })

    output$show = renderPlot({
        shiny::req(plotData())
        d = plotData()
        print("refresh")
        plot(d$x,d$y, pch = as.integer(d$type))
    })


    observe({
        n = input$n
        a = input$auto
        type = input$type

        if (type == "a") return(NULL)
        if (a) shiny::updateSliderInput(session, "y", value = switch(type, "15" = 8, "21" = 9))
    })
}
shiny::shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The problem is that the plot is rendered twice when the user selects either type 15 or 21. That is caused by the fact that when `plotData` changes, `updateSliderInput` is executed before `renderPlot`. (I have seen this behavior with the `reactlog` package.) However, I don't know how to solve this. I've tried a bunch of functions, such as `isolate`, `req`, but without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid triggering reactives or outputs unnecessarily you should almost alway use `freezeReactiveValue` when using an `update*` function in [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny):

```
library(shiny)

ui = shiny::fluidPage(
  shiny::sidebarLayout(
    shiny::sidebarPanel(
      shiny::radioButtons("type", "Type", choices = c("5", "15", "21")),
      shiny::sliderInput("x", "x", min = 1, max = 10, value = 7),
      shiny::checkboxInput("auto","Set y to 8 when type is 15, and 9 when type is 21", value = TRUE),
      shiny::sliderInput("y", "y", min = 1, max = 10, value = 7)
    ),
    shiny::mainPanel(
      shiny::plotOutput("show")
    )
  )
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  plotData = shiny::reactive({
    list(x = input$x, y = input$y, type = input$type)
  })
  
  observe({
    n = input$n
    a = input$auto
    type = input$type
    
    if (type == "a") return(NULL)
    freezeReactiveValue(input, "y")
    if (a) shiny::updateSliderInput(session, "y", value = switch(type, "15" = 8, "21" = 9))
  }, priority = 1)
  
  output$show = renderPlot({
    shiny::req(plotData())
    d = plotData()
    print("refresh")
    plot(d$x,d$y, pch = as.integer(d$type))
  })
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Please see this [related chapter](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-dynamic.html#freezing-reactive-inputs) from *Mastering Shiny*.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed that it only worked when the `observe` chunk is placed above `renderPlot`.

Comment: That is just to get the initialization of the app right. You can achive the same by increasing the observers `priority = 1` (if you want to keep the order of the code). Personally I'd prefer setting the output at the end of the script.

Comment: @MartijnTennekes another comment on your code: you should be aware of the fact that using `::` costs time - not much but it adds up. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23232888/9841389).

Comment: I will use this code for an upcoming CRAN package. I will put shiny into the "suggests" lists to minimize the dependency overload, and place the app in a `if (requireNamespace("shiny")) {}` statement. Do you know if CRAN accepts function calls without `::`?

Comment: I'll stay with the double-column. Do you perhaps know the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71300472/shiny-how-to-fix-sidebarpanel-when-mainpanel-is-scrollable?