# Shiny: how to make titlebarPanel- and sidebarPanel sticky when mainPanel is scrollable, but not for mobile screens

Tags: r, shiny

How can I fix the position of the sidebarPanel and the titlePanel when the mainPanel is scrollable, but only for desktop screens (so not for mobile phone screens)?

So far, thanks to @ismirsehregal, I got this:

```
library(shiny)
library(kableExtra)

ui = shiny::fluidPage(
    tags$style(HTML("div.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}")),
    shiny::titlePanel("Title"),
    
    shiny::sidebarLayout(
        tagAppendAttributes(shiny::sidebarPanel(
            shiny::sliderInput("n", "n", min = 20, max = 100, value = 20, step = 5),
        ), class = "sticky"),
        shiny::mainPanel(
            shiny::tableOutput("show")
        )
    )
)
server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$show = function() {
        df = data.frame(i  = 1:input$n)
        kableExtra::kbl(df)
    }
}
shiny::shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In desktop mode this is ok:
[image]

In mobile phone mode (so with small window, where the mainPanel is placed under the sidebarPanel), I don't want the sidebarPanel to be sticky, because otherwise the table will disappear behind the sidebarPanel like this:

[image]

Comment: I don't get what you expected result is. What do you mean with `Title appears when scrolling down`? On my machine it's hidden when scrolling down.

Comment: The expected result is that the title also stays fixed (above the sidebarPanel)

Comment: Why don't you mention this in your question?

Comment: Question updated! Thanks.

Comment: I rephrased the question. Apologies for the confusion, @ismirsehregal

Answer (score 2):

We can use [CSS property](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp) `position: sticky;` to achive this:

```
library(shiny)
library(kableExtra)

ui = shiny::fluidPage(
  tags$style(HTML("div.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}")),
  shiny::sidebarLayout(
    tagAppendAttributes(shiny::sidebarPanel(
      shiny::sliderInput("n", "n", min = 20, max = 100, value = 20, step = 5),
    ), class = "sticky"),
    shiny::mainPanel(
      shiny::tableOutput("show")
    )
  )
)
server = function(input, output, session) {
  output$show = function() {
    df = data.frame(i  = 1:input$n)
    kableExtra::kbl(df)
  }
}
shiny::shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks! I have the same two issues that I mentioned in reply of the first answer. Application: the function `c4a_gui()` from `https://github.com/mtennekes/cols4all`

Comment: Have you tried with the latest edit - setting the z-index?

Comment: Yes, see update

Answer (score 1):

We could use `style = "position:fixed;width:inherit;"` in the sidebarPanel:

```
library("shiny")

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel(
    "Fixed"
  ),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    
    sidebarPanel(
      style = "position:fixed;width:inherit;",
      "Inputs",
      width = 4,
      sliderInput("n", "n", min = 20, max = 100, value = 20, step = 5)),
    
    
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("show"),
      width = 8)
    
  ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$show = function() {
    df = data.frame(i  = 1:input$n)
    kableExtra::kbl(df)
  }
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, but introduces two new issues: 1) the titlePanel itself is not fixed 2) it goes wrong when the window is made smaller (and shiny normally puts the main panel under instead of at the right-hand-side of the sidebar panel). Do you know how to solve these?

Comment: 1. Apply the code to titel panel also to fix. 2. Try the same xode with height . Can not test at the moment on mobile device!

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it didn't work.