# dplyr::group_by() or just > group_by()

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, operators

I am getting into the programming language R, and I would like to know the difference between dplyr::group_by() or just  group_by()?, what does this operator "::" do?.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it a good practice to call functions in a package via ::](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23232791/is-it-a-good-practice-to-call-functions-in-a-package-via)

Answer (score 1):

The first would be appropriate when you were uncertain that the dplyr package were loaded. The two would be equivalent if it were loaded.

Comment: I also want to add that :: is useful in case you have two packages loaded that have the same function name. select() is an example here. dplyr::select is useful if you have plyr loaded because you were using ddply() or something like that, since select() is also a function in plyr

Comment: Yes. However, I don’t think that is an issue with ’group_by’. … yet.

Comment: I think you've misused the terminology:  having `dplyr` loaded doesn't mean its exported functions are visible, that's having it "attached".  Being attached implies being loaded, but you can have a lot of packages loaded but not attached, so their functions aren't available without the `::` prefix.

Comment: @user2554330 : you might be right, although most people use ‘library (tidyverse)’ and I’m pretty sure that exposes ‘group_by’. I know this because I formerly would use ‘library(dplyr)’ when attempting answers to Hadley erase Q’s and then there was alway two or three missing functions that were being used that needed to be looked up to see which package was being assumed but not stated.

Comment: The `tidyverse` package is unusual in that it attaches a bunch of other packages when you attach it.  So `library(tidyverse)` gets `dplyr` attached as well.  In a new session, `library(tidyverse)` will add about 9 entries to the search list.

Comment: If you run `sessionInfo()`, the last part of the listing gives all the packages that are loaded and not attached.  I see 43 of them after running `library(tidyverse)`.

Answer (score 1):

In `dplyr::group_by(...)`, the `::` operator says to load the `dplyr` package if necessary, and to select the `group_by` function from that package.

Without the `dplyr::` prefix, it just says to find a function named `group_by` in the current environment or its ancestor environments (which include all packages in the `search()` list).

Using `::` is a bit safer (in a long script or package you might have created a local function named `group_by` and you didn't mean to run that one, or some other package may have a function with that name), but also a bit slower.

Once you're writing R packages (which is easier than you think), you can import `group_by` explicitly from `dplyr`, and get both advantages:  safety and speed.  It's kind of equivalent to doing

```
group_by <- dplyr::group_by
... many uses of group_by here ...
```

where you only pay the cost of `::` once.

Comment: Also - the `::` helps resolve namespace collisions where multiple packages are loaded that have conflicting function names. E.g. `stats::filter()` vs `dplyr::filter()`. The [{conflicted}](https://github.com/r-lib/conflicted) package is a great tool to alleviate this issue.

Comment: That's really the same issue.  If both `stats` and `dplyr` are attached, both versions of `filter` will be found in ancestors of the current environment.  R will pick the first one it finds.  Whether that's the one from `stats` or from `dplyr` depends on where they are in the search list.

Comment: Fair enough, but 'ancestors' is a bit of an esoteric term so it might improve the answer to explain a bit further.

Comment: @DanAdams: I've made a small edit.