# How do I make a column that sums only numeric columns?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a lot of columns.

```
LABEL    COL1  COL2  COL3
Meat     10    20    30
Veggies  20    30    40
```

How do I make column named `SUMCOL` that adds up `COL1`, `COL2`, `COL3`, and any other numeric columns I add?

Example of `SUMCOL` with just the above columns:

```
SUMCOL
60
90
```

Comment: `dat$SUMCOL <- rowSums(dat[-1]) ` where dat is the name of your data.frame. Or a bit more flexible `dat$SUMCOL <- rowSums(dat[sapply(dat, is.numeric)]) `.

Comment: `df$SUMCOL <- rowSums(df[sapply(df, is.numeric)], na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: I ended up using `dat$SUMCOL <- rowSums(dat[sapply(dat, is.numeric)])` from @imo's code

Comment: @Username, perhaps you'd like to post it as a solution and accept the answer (noting it's from `lmo`). Or if `lmo` can post as an answer even better.

Comment: I was waiting for @Imo to post, but I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using this code:

`df$SUMCOL <- rowSums(df[sapply(df, is.numeric)], na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function, which takes advantage of `select_if` and scoped argument `is_numeric`

```
myfun <- function(df) {
               require(dplyr)
               y <- select_if(df, is_numeric)
               rowSums(y, na.rm=T)
         }
```

#### Solution

```
df$SUMCOL <- myfun(df)
```

#### Output

```
    LABEL COL1 COL2 COL3 SUMCOL
1    Meat   10   20   30     60
2 Veggies   20   30   40     90
```

Comment: `select_if` is not a base R function... Nor is `is_numeric`.

Comment: If you are building a function that requires a package, it would be more portable to include the library call inside of the function, probably with `require`.

Comment: Is there a difference between `require` and `library`?

Comment: @ChiPak Yes, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595512/what-is-the-difference-between-require-and-library skim the accepted answer. Look at the other ones as well.

Comment: `require` will fail gracefully, printing a warning if the package is not found, whereas `library` will throw an error. Try `library(blah)` and then `require(blah)` for an example. From `?require` *require is designed for use inside other functions*

Comment: Thanks to you both.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but there's a tidy way to do this with just dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

#Create dataset
data <- tibble(LABEL = c("Meat", "Veggies"),
               COL1 = c(10, 20),
               COL2 = c(20, 30),
               COL3 = c(30, 40))

data %>%
  mutate(SUMCOL = select(., starts_with("COL")) %>%
         rowSums(na.rm = TRUE))
```

In case anyone is unfamiliar with this syntax, it basically says "make (mutate) a new column called SUMCOL. To do so, select all columns (that's the period), but perform rowSums only on the columns that start with "COL" (as an aside, you also could list out the columns with c("COL1", "COL2", "COL3") and ignore any missing values.