# error message when using mutate function in r

Tags: r, dplyr

receiving the following error message:
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: argument "no" is missing, with no default.

```
 mutate(x,perfLev= ifelse(SS< 1438, "Below Basic",
                   ifelse(SS>= 1439 & SS <= 1499, "Basic",
                   ifelse(SS >= 1500 & SS <= 1545, "Proficient",
                   ifelse(SS >= 1546, "Advanced")))))
```

Comment: Try `case_when()` instead

Comment: The `no` (last) argument in your last ifelse function is missing, and it doesn't have a default value.

Answer (score 3):

Using comments by Make212 and Renu, here's one option for fixing it:

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(x,
       perfLev = case_when(
         SS <  1438              ~ "Below Basic",
         SS >= 1439 & SS <= 1499 ~ "Basic",
         SS >= 1500 & SS <= 1545 ~ "Proficient",
         SS >= 1546              ~ "Advanced",
         TRUE                    ~ "huh?"
       ) )
```

I added a "default" (`TRUE`), which is generally good (explicit code). Note that if you do not include the `TRUE`, then it would get an `NA` value, in case that's what you want. I can see it happening here if any of the following are true:

- `is.na(SS)`
- `SS >= 1438 & SS < 1439`
- `SS >  1499 & SS < 1500`
- `SS >  1545 & SS < 1546`

You may not need it if `NA` is acceptable and you are *guaranteed* of `SS`'s integrality.

This code is equivalent to a slight fix to your code:

```
mutate(x,
       perfLev = 
         ifelse(SS < 1438, "Below Basic",
                ifelse(SS >= 1439 & SS <= 1499, "Basic",
                       ifelse(SS >= 1500 & SS <= 1545, "Proficient",
                              ifelse(SS >= 1546, "Advanced", "huh?"))))
       )
```

Indentation for style/clarity only.

Comment: (I really wish R supported python's chaining of comparisons, such as `1499 < SS < 1500` ... I understand why it won't happen, but still ...)

Comment: If you are using `case_when`, then you can also use `between` rather than `a < b < c`

Comment: @MrFlick, except that they are both-closed, meaning `between` gives you `a <= b <= c`. In his examples, you are right, I should have included that, but I often need open-ends, too.

Comment: I just ran a quick test with 1e5 random `SS`, and `dplyr::case_when` was ~2x faster than `dplyr::if_else`, and it was ~5x faster than `base::ifelse`. In this example. With four nested conditionals. I can find performance-parity when `n` is around 200, so if your data is smaller then performance is likely not a consideration; if your data is larger, then you will be faster with either of `dplyr`'s functions.

Answer (score 1):

`case_when` is used to vectorize multiple `if/else` statements

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(x,perfLev= case_when(
                   SS < 1438 ~ "Below Basic",
                   SS >= 1439 & SS <= 1499 ~ "Basic",
                   SS >= 1500 & SS <= 1545 ~ "Proficient",
                   SS >= 1546 ~ "Advanced"))
```

Comment: Poll: any reason you prefer `require` over `library`? (I've found only one use-case where I find its behavior desirable, otherwise I agree with Hadley's discussion [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html), search down for *"There are four functions ..."*.)

Comment: @r2evans I remember referencing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595512/what-is-the-difference-between-require-and-library) post and deciding it doesn't really matter unless you're writing packaged functions. The main difference is that `library` throws an error if a package isn't found, where as `require` returns `TRUE/FALSE`. I've just defaulted to `require` for a long time, and I've never had any issues, but I can see the argument for `library` since it throws an explicit error.

Comment: I'm familiar with that post and the argument, and when I was learning R, I started using `require`. I promptly stopped when I jumped to another computer, sourced a `quux.R` file, and it skimmed past that line (which silently returned `FALSE` without stopping) and failed later. I had to bring in the file line-by-line, which is where I found the mistake. Another common discussion/debate is Yihui's [library-vs-require](https://yihui.name/en/2014/07/library-vs-require/). Thanks, this was just an unofficial poll :-)

Comment: @r2evans thanks for the reading material, I might just consider switching to `library`

Comment: Thanks so much for your time !

Answer (score 1):

Though OP has mentioned about problem with `ifelse` use in `mutate` but I thought to mention that in such scenario `cut` provides better option.

One can simply write as:

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
mutate(perfLev = cut(SS, breaks = c(0, 1438, 1499, 1545, +Inf), 
    labels = c("Below Basic", "Basic", "Proficient", "Advanced"))) 

#OR

x$perfLev <- cut(SS, breaks = c(0, 1438, 1499, 1545, +Inf), 
    labels = c("Below Basic", "Basic", "Proficient", "Advanced"))
```

> The logic to match `breaks` with `labels` can be simplified by writing
>   in down in a tabular format and use it as hint. The option for the above case could be as:
>
> ```
> 0
> 1438    --    "Below Basic"
> 1499    --    "Basic"
> 1545    --    "Proficient"
> +inf    --    "Advanced"
> ```