# Concatenating strings with multiple separators using paste() in R

Tags: r

See the following reproducible example:

```
require(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)
reprex_df <- data.frame(
  var1 = sample(1:10),
  var2 = sample(11:20),
  var3 = sample(21:30)
)
```

I am trying to create a new column containing URLs created from concatenating the other variables from each row into a string with "https://www.google.com/search?q=", using the following code:

```
reprex_df %>% mutate(new_col = c(paste("https://www.google.com/search?q=", var1, var2, var3, sep="+")))
```

Which results in:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=+3+13+30
```

The problem with this is that it puts a `+` between the `https://www.google.com/search?q=` and `var1`, which is not a valid format for the URL. I need no separator between these strings. Like so:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=3+13+30
```

Can I somehow specify to use a different separator for this part of the conjunction using `paste()`, or do I have to take a totally different approach? Any ideas?

Comment: Note, [don’t use `require`, use `library`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51263513/1968).

Comment: For anyone wondering, this is because require() returns a logical, which is useful for loading it conditionally, or inside a function that needs to run even the library is not found. Library() is more appropriate for setting up the general environment.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I'll add to that (though significantly more *objective*): in questions, load packages you need, not a meta package that imports 25 other (sometimes large) packages. Be kind to your answerers, I'm typically looking at things within an already-running R session, and since I do not personally load all of those packages, I don't want to have them in the namespace (oh, the collisions!). It's python's equivalent of `from pkgname import *`, which is both discouraged and (again, objectively) sloppy for namespace management. (Yes ... it's just *my* opinion.)

Comment: @r2evans Totally agree, and not just in questions but generally in code. The Tidyverse is amazing. The `tidyverse` (package) is bad.

Comment: I wonder if one could ever justify `library(*)` (in R) or `from * import *` (in python) to see the massive conflagration of collisions and other problems ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. **`paste0`**  Perhaps the easiest way is to specify the + signs as arguments with `paste0` rather than using `sep`:

   ```
   root <- "https://www.google.com/search?q="
   reprex_df %>% 
     mutate(new_col = paste0(root, var1, "+", var2, "+", var3))
   ```
2. **`sprintf`** `sprintf` is another possibility:

   ```
   fmt <- "https://www.google.com/search?q=%d+%d+%d"
   reprex_df %>%
     mutate(new_col = sprintf(fmt, var1, var2, var3))
   ```
3. **`sub`** Yet another possibility is to use the code in the question but follow it with code to remove the first +:

   ```
   root <- "https://www.google.com/search?q="
   reprex_df %>% 
     mutate(new_col = paste(root, var1, var2, var3, sep="+"),
            new_col = sub("\\+", "", new_col))
   ```
4. **`allow extra +`** Google ignores the + after the equal sign so another approach is to just allow the extra plus to exist.

   ```
   root <- "https://www.google.com/search?q="
   reprex_df %>% 
     mutate(new_col = paste(root, var1, var2, var3, sep="+"))
   ```

Comment: Very comprehensive. Giving you the Answer on this one.

Answer (score 6):

You need another `paste`

```
reprex_df %>%
  mutate(new_col = paste0(
    "https://www.google.com/search?q=",
    paste(var1, var2, var3, sep = "+")
  ))
#   var1 var2 var3                                  new_col
#1     3   13   30  https://www.google.com/search?q=3+13+30
#2     4   12   22  https://www.google.com/search?q=4+12+22
#3     5   16   26  https://www.google.com/search?q=5+16+26
# ...
```

---

If you don't want to type all the variable names `var1` to `varn` try `purrr::invoke`, thanks to @thelatemail

```
reprex_df %>%
  mutate(new_col = paste0("https://www.google.com/search?q=", 
                          invoke(paste, ., sep = "+")
                          )
         )
```

Or in `base R`

```
url <- "https://www.google.com/search?q=" # optional
transform(reprex_df,
          new_col = paste0(url, do.call(paste, c(reprex_df, sep = "+"))))
```

Comment: Quite sensible. Thank you.

Comment: And if you don't want to type out `var1-varn` you could use `do.call` or the `purrr` `invoke()` wrapper - `reprex_df %>%
  mutate(new_col = paste0(
    "https://www.google.com/search?q=",
    invoke(paste, ., sep="+")
  ))`