# DT tables not shown in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a shiny app that opens with a simple .bat file that executes R and the script run.r in the background. The shiny use the package `DT` extensively to render all the tables. The problem i'm having is that if i run the shiny from Rstudio run app it shows all the tables but if I execute the shiny with the .bat file it just doesn't show theme. I have done this like 4 times and it is the first time it happens and I don't know the problem. I have the latest version of the pacakges of the `DT` available in CRAN,

So my `server.r` is :

```
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  observeEvent(input$run,{

TablasVaR <- function(mat,DT = T){
      mat_tbl <- data.frame(Activos = rownames(mat),Porcentaje = mat[,"Porcentaje"],
                            VaR = mat[,"Nivel"])

      tabla <- datatable(mat_tbl, escape = T,rownames = FALSE, 
                         selection = list(target = 'row'),
                         options = list(dom = 'tip', paging = TRUE))%>%
        formatStyle(1:ncol(mat_tbl),fontSize = '100%')%>%
        formatCurrency(3,digits = 0)%>%
        formatPercentage(2,digits = 1)
      if(DT){
        return(tabla)
      } else{
        return(mat_tbl)
      }

    }

    matr <- data.frame(Porcentaje=rnorm(19),Nivel = rnorm(19))



  output$table <- renderDataTable({TablasVaR(matr)})
  })
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    stopApp()
  })  
}
```

the `ui.r` is

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(),
    wellPanel(style = "background-color: #ffffff;",
              bsButton("run","run1",block=F, style="default"),
              fluidRow(column(4,align="center",offset = 4,
                              dataTableOutput("table"))))
  ))
```

the `run.r` is:

```
librerias <- c("openxlsx","ggplot2","scales","rugarch","zoo","data.table","stringr",
               "DT","plotly","lubridate","knitr","gridExtra","grid","shinyBS",
               "rmarkdown","nloptr","shiny")
if(length(setdiff(librerias, rownames(installed.packages()))) > 0){
  install.packages(setdiff(librerias, rownames(installed.packages())))
}
invisible(sapply(librerias, require, character.only = TRUE))
CAMINO <<- "D:/Users/aandr/Documents/Ejemplo/"
runApp(CAMINO, launch.browser=TRUE)
```

and the .bat file contains:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.1\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH "run.r"
```

if I run the shiny app from the `run.r` the `DT` is display, but if I run it from the .bat file it wont.
To make it run you will need to save the server.r, ui.r, run.r and .bat in the same folder.

Comment: We're not like to be able to help without something reproducible. Can you add a representative but small shiny app to your question?

Comment: @r2evans just added a minimal example which cause the problem in my pc.

Comment: Nice MWE, btw, it made the difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you read RStudio's page on [*Using DT in Shiny*](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html), you may not have noticed

> Note that in **DT**, `DTOutput()` is an alias of `dataTableOutput()`, and `renderDT()` is an alias of `renderDataTable()`. You are recommended to use `DTOutput()` and `renderDT()` to avoid possible collisions with functions of the same names in **shiny** (`shiny::dataTableOutput()` and `shiny::renderDataTable()`).

Collisions, that's your problem. To confirm, if you see this:

```
find("dataTableOutput")
# [1] "package:DT"    "package:shiny"
find("renderDataTable")
# [1] "package:DT"    "package:shiny"
```

then the function name collision is likely to blame. Try replacing your `dataTableOutput(...)` with either `DT::dataTableOutput(...)` or `DTOutput(...)`; and replace `renderDataTable(...)` with either `DT::renderDataTable(...)` or `renderDT(...)`.

Comment: I have not seen the `DTOutput` functions before but that's exactly the problem, so annoying it work on Rstudio for some reason and in the R console it didn't. Thanks

Comment: That's a pretty bad collision to have, especially when both packages are authored by the same group. (tidyverse suffers from this, too.) My preference has been to be specific with `DT::renderDataTable`, but the aliases work fine, too. Glad to help. (I've been considering using `loadNamespace(...)` instead of `library`, in part to force me to use `DT::`. I haven't found where this breaks, though I'm sure I'm missing something. BTW: using `require` in your code is incorrect: if you don't check its return then use `library`. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51263513/3358272

Comment: I used to use the DT:: in previous shiny apps i don't now why i change that in this one but won't do it never again. Thanks for the `require``comment

Comment: With collisions more common these days, I really like python's import mechanisms: `import pkgname` forces `pkgname.func`, which is explicit and clear; `import pkgname as pkg` allows short-cutting, which can be clear and less inconvenient, wish R had this mechanism.

Comment: Something more basic like a real warning (not the message it currently shows) would work.

Comment: There are so many collisions these days and so many scripts that use `options(warn=2)` (error instead of warning), this would be a backward-incompatible change in behavior. I don't disagree, though, R's method of namespace management could use a few tweaks.