# How to keep only the first Character of a string before space, and all the characters after space in R

Tags: r, regex, data.table

I have the following `data.table`

`library(data.table)`

`dt <- data.table(c('Female 18 - 24', 'Male 18+', 'People 18 -54'))`

How can I transform it to

`dt <- data.table(c('F 18 - 24', 'M 18+', 'P 18 -54'))` using `regex` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 gsub('(^[A-Z])[A-Za-z]+\\s(*.)','\\1 \\2',c('Female 18 - 24', 'Male 18+', 'People 18 -54'))
 [1] "F 18 - 24" "M 18+"     "P 18 -54"
```

`(^[A-Z])` take the first letter as group1

`[A-Za-z]+\\s` any number of small letters follwed by a space

`(*.)` take any thing come after a space as group2

`'\\1 \\2'` Finally, return group1 and group2 separated by a space

Comment: it worked. thanks. could you please provide some explanation also ?

Comment: or `gsub("^(.)[^ ]* (.*)", "\\1 \\2", x)`

Answer (score 0):

```
require(data.table)
require(stringi)
dt <- data.table(V1=c('Female 18 - 24', 'Male 18+', 'People 18 -54'))
dt[,V2:= stri_replace_first_regex(V1,"(?<=\\w)\\w+","")]  
dt

           V1        V2
1: Female 18 - 24    F 18 - 24
2: Male 18+          M 18+
3: People 18 -54     P 18 -54
```

Comment: Don't use `require` when you just want to load the package. Use `library`. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595512/what-is-the-difference-between-require-and-library/51263513) for more details.