# How to suppress messages from a package dependency to my own package build?

Tags: r, package, roxygen2

My question is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681688/disable-messages-upon-loading-a-package) except that I'm looking to apply this specifically within a package that I am building. As such, I don't call `library()` to bring in packages my package depends on, but I am using the following `roxygen2` setup (as an example):

```
#' @rawNamespace import(shiny, except = c(dataTableOutput, renderDataTable))
#' @import dplyr
#' @importFrom ggalt stat_xspline
```

My problem is that calling the `ggalt` package brings in the following undesirable message into the console when my package is loaded, and I would like R to suppress this:

```
Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'ggalt':
  method                  from   
  grid.draw.absoluteGrob  ggplot2
  grobHeight.absoluteGrob ggplot2
  grobWidth.absoluteGrob  ggplot2
  grobX.absoluteGrob      ggplot2
  grobY.absoluteGrob      ggplot2
```

As per the question I linked above, I could use `suppressMessages()` if I were calling that package using `library()`. But would I do so within the `roxygen2` infrastructure? Is it possible to apply this within the `#' @rawNamespace import()` line somehow? I'm having trouble finding documentation about what arguments this function provides other than `except`.

I also note [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53941218/r-package-development-how-to-suppress-messages-generated-from-dependency-package), but this seems more focused on the package development stage, whereas my issue is more for the end-user of my completed package having the message suppressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a way to do what you want, but I don't recommend that you use it.  You may run into complaints from CRAN at some point if you do.

Think of a user who is using one of those `ggplot2` methods, who then loads your package.  Your package will cause `ggalt` to load, and will change the implementation of those functions to the ones that override them.  The user should be told about that.  If they don't want to hear it (because this is part of a document, or something), then *they* should suppress the messages, you shouldn't.

So, now you know why you shouldn't suppress them, here's how you could probably do it.  Instead of importing `stat_xspline` from `ggalt`, make `ggalt` into a suggested package, and test for it and load it explicitly when you need it.  The explicit load should allow you to suppress any messages that it generates.

Comment: Thanks, this is a private package of a shiny app for my employer, and won't be subject to CRAN inspection,

Comment: I don't see how that matters.  If you don't have any users other than a server hosting the Shiny app, then the messages won't matter, so just ignore them.  But if individual users might use your package to run the Shiny app locally, they'll be put at risk without knowing it.