# Categorical ordering (unexpected behavior - order is reversed)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Goal is to achieve ordered categories on y axis.

`y1 -> y2 -> y3`.

Here's the example:

```
require(data.table)
require(ggplot2)

dt <- data.table(var = rep("x1", 3),
                 categ = paste0("y", c(1,2,3)),
                 value = c(-2,0.5,-1))

ggplot(dt, aes(x = categ, y = value)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    coord_flip() +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

It seems to be reversed. Here's the one way to achieve desired ordering in `ggplot2`:

```
dt$categ <- factor(dt$categ, levels = rev(levels(factor(dt$categ))))

ggplot(dt, aes(x = categ, y = value)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    coord_flip() +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

Great, now ordering seems to be right. But with some modifications:

```
ggplot(dt, aes(x = categ, y = value)) +
    geom_bar(data = dt[value < 0], stat = "identity", fill = "darkred") +
    geom_bar(data = dt[value >= 0], stat = "identity", fill = "darkblue") +
    coord_flip() +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

For some reason factor ordering is ignored here. Any clues why?

Comment: [Don’t use `require`, use `library`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51263513/1968)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution could be:

```
# dt is original data without factors
ggplot(dt, aes(categ, value, fill = value >= 0)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkred", "darkblue")) +
  # since we want y1 on top and y3 on bottom we have to apply rev
  scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(dt$categ)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()
```

Trick is to pass `dt$categ` as `limits` argument to `scale_x_discrete()`. In your first plot order **is not reversed**, this is how it should be as `ggplot2` starts putting values from the origin of the axis (`0`).

[image]

I also removed two `geom_bar` lines that were used in a *not-ggplot* way.

Comment: The difference in the order between plot 2 and 3 from the question comes from the fact that, as @PoGibas pointed out, using two geom_bars with different color is not how you should do things with ggplot!

Comment: Setting the limits in `scale_x_discrete` makes the ordering of the factor superfluous but is not necessary to solve your problem (as you already put your factor levels in the correct order). So you need either the `scale_x_discrete(...)` **or** `dt$categ <- factor(..., levels = ...)`.

Comment: I might have oversimplified my example little bit too much, but some points mentioned in answer have indeed helped. There are more issues when you add two more dimensions and make `facet_grid`. I suppose I should re-formulate question and create a better example.