# r Blastula Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = h) : MAIL failed: 530

Tags: r, email, curl

NOOB question related to R blastula.
I am trying to send an email with blastula using office365.
I was able to create a credentials file but can't seem to send a simple test email:

```
require(blastula) ; require(curl)
email <- compose_email(body = "Insert your e-mail body here",  footer = "Insert your e-mail footer here")
email %>% smtp_send(from = "me@email.com", to = "someone_else@email.com", credentials = creds_file("C:/Users/me/CREDS_FILE")
)
```

There seems be a dependency on curl that's throwing the error:
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = h) : MAIL failed: 530

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: [Always use `library`, not `require`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51263513/1968).

Comment: I'm having the same problem (yesterday it worked). You found an answer?

Comment: hey same issue here @user2948714, you achieve to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try use_ssl = TRUE in create_smtp_creds_key. This worked for me.

```
email <- compose_email(
body = md(
  "Your email message"
))
smtp <- create_smtp_creds_key(
  id = "outlook",
  user = "youremail@outlook.com",
  provider = "office365",
  host = "smtp.office365.com",
  use_ssl = TRUE)
 email %>%
smtp_send(to = to,
          from = from,
          subject = subject,
          credentials = creds_key(id = "outlook"))
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing some searching around I found this [question and answer](https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/1079) which seemed related.  Hadley's suggestion of restarting R and reinstalling {curl} fixed the issue that I was having.

I actually reinstalled both {curl} and {blastula} with

```
install.packages(c('blastula', 'curl'))
```

Comment: Thanks Konrad, I gave you a point for the effort.  Unfortunately this did not solve the curl_fetch_memory mail failed: 530 error

Comment: reinstalling both the packages did not solve the problem for me.