# multiway::corcondia() on parafac and parafac2 object returns Na_real_

Tags: r, tensor, decomposition

I am trying to fit a PARAFAC model on a 4 dimensional set of FTIR spectra organised in a matrix:

```
dim(matrix)

6844, 34, 147
```

When I run

```
library(multiway)
parafac<-parafac(matrix, nfac=3, nstart=1)
cor<-corcondia(matrix, parafac)

cor

[1] NA
```

The same happens with any value of `nfac` argument

If I got the theory behind parafac right, this should not happen with the core consistency test.

Comment: Unrelated, but [use `library` instead of `require`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51263513/1968).

Comment: Thank you @KonradRudolph. I amended the text. Would you have a minute to explain why library should be used in this case?

Comment: The link in my previous comment explains this in great detail.