# How to know which package hold current function in R?

Tags: r

When I `?filter`,Rstudio let me choose:

```
Help on topic 'filter' was found in the following packages:

Linear Filtering on a Time Series
(in package stats in library C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.3/library)
Return rows with matching conditions
(in package dplyr in library C:/Users/me/Documents/.checkpoint/2019-12-11/lib/x86_64-w64-mingw32/3.5.3)
```

When I use `filter()` in my script,how to know is it `stats::filter()` or `dplyr::filter()`?

Comment: Just type `filter` without `()` and look at `<environment: namespace:stats>` or `<environment: namespace:dplyr>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the following to find the package name that a function is currently loaded from

```
environmentName(environment(filter))
```

As for handling it I would stick with using `stats::filter()` or `dplyr::filter()` if it's only a few uses or declaring one as a new function altogther

```
filter_stats <- stats::filter
filter_stats()
```

The library `conflicted` is also useful for conflicts especially with `conflict_scout()` and `conflict_prefer()`.  You could do `conflict_prefer("filter", "stats")`, for example, to override the default behavior of the most recent package taking priority.  [There are a few other alternative methods mentioned on the conflicted libraries readme.](https://github.com/r-lib/conflicted)

There are also the base calls `conflicts()` or `conflicts(detail = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 2):

The generic solution is to inspect `topenv(environment(function_name))` (and potentially calling `environmentName` on the result). But just printing `function_name` (i.e. using the name without calling it) also works.

That said, this should generally *not* be used as a mechanism at runtime; instead, ensure that the expected packages are loaded. The easiest ways of doing this are:

1. Either use explicit namespace qualification, i.e. `dplyr::filter` instead of `filter`; this is best practice in most modern languages, but it can be quite burdensome, especially when doing exploratory analysis.
2. [Always use `library` instead of `require`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51263513/1968) when importing a package. Unlike `require`, `library` will raise an error if the corresponding package couldn’t be loaded.

Comment: then,if I want to use `base::function`,should I add `base::` before function name?

Comment: @kittygirl Good question. *Generally* people don’t do this. Firstly, it would be unpractical since the resulting R code would be extremely unreadable. Secondly, when people override names from ‘base’ (which they rarely do to start with!) they usually tend to do it in such a way that the function can be used as a drop-in replacement to the ‘base’ function, and it’s generally seen as bad style to do otherwise. Ultimately I am not aware of *anybody* who explicitly uses `base::` except in specific cases.