# Why require() command is preferred within functions in R?

Tags: r

I notice that lots of functions contain `require()` to attach a specific package. Some documents announce that require is mostly used within functions while `library()` should be used at the beginning. 
I have known that `library()` will throw out an error while `require()` will give a logical output when facing errors. But why should we mostly use `require()` within a function definition?

Comment: This post explains the difference between them https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595512/what-is-the-difference-between-require-and-library

Comment: @RonakShah Hi, thanks for the link. But I don't think the answers there are for this question. I know the differences between the two but I do not know the reason we should use require inside a function.