# Why object size are different in R?

Tags: r, object, memory

I wrote the following in RStudio but the result is amazing !!!

```
rm(list = ls())
require(lobstr)
x <- 1:3
tracemem(x)
y <- x
x[1] <- 4L
obj_size(x)
obj_size(y)
```

Why they are different?

Comment: Tangent: you're using `require` wrong, either use `library` or check require's return value, ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51263513/3358272.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R uses special compact storage for sequences.  When you change the first entry, it drops back to the standard storage.

The special storage is actually *inefficient* for a short sequence like `1:3`, but the size would be the same for `1:3000000`:

```r
rm(list = ls())
library(lobstr)
x <- 1:3
y <- x
x[1] <- 4L
obj_size(x)
#> 64 B
obj_size(y)
#> 680 B

x <- 1:3000000
y <- x
x[1] <- 4L
obj_size(x)
#> 12,000,048 B
obj_size(y)
#> 680 B
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

It's also quite hard to define the size of objects in R.  For example, a sequence of length 3 (or 3 million) takes up 680 bytes, but two of them don't take up twice that:

```r
x <- 1:3
obj_size(x)
#> 680 B
y <- 1:3000000
obj_size(y)
#> 680 B
z <- list(x, y)
obj_size(z)
#> 896 B
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The size of `z` would contain the size of the `list()` container as well as the two objects bound to `x` and `y`, but it's still only 216 bytes bigger than each of them.  This is because some of the size attributed to `x` and `y` is shared:  they're both the same kind of special object, so the code to handle that is only stored once.