# Align values based on digits and disregard minus sign/prefix

Tags: r, alignment, stargazer

I want the data output in table form, but I'm struggling to align the values in a way that disregards the minus sign in front of negative values. Been researching for a while to no avail. Hopefully there's a simple solution.

Please see included code sample and image link below.

```
#install.packages("stargazer")
library(stargazer)

df<-as.data.frame(array(data=c(1.33,-1.23,23.4343,-3000)))
  
stargazer(df, type = "text", 
          title            = "Align me plz",
          rownames         = FALSE,
          colnames         = FALSE,
          summary          = FALSE
)
```

[image: Screenshot of the table]

Comment: Welcome to SO, Sindre! zx8754 just suggested an edit for your question that changed `require` to `library`, which has a not-insignificant difference, look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51263513/3358272. Long-story-short, if you use `require`, you really need to capture it's return value and do something with it, otherwise your code is fragile. (I second the comment asking for the linked image.)

Comment: Thanks for the input, guys. Hopefully I've successfully added the image now. Looking forward to more insights.

Comment: Seems like the `align` argument may be relevant: `align`: a logical value indicating whether numeric values in the same column should be
_aligned at the decimal mark_ in LaTeX output. Requires `\usepackage{dcolumn}`
in LaTeX preamble."

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Henrik. It seems dcolumn is a Latex package. I'm trying to figure out how to implement that in R studios.

Comment: What is the output you ultimately want.  Do you want it to be decimal aligned, or do you just want the positive numbers pushed to the right one space?

Comment: @DaveArmstrong, I would like them to be decimal aligned.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't solve the problem, but perhaps points to the culprit.  First, it doesn't look like there is an alignment option when the output is `"text"`.  I tried to force the alignment changing the numbers into character strings as follows:

```
df<-data.frame(x=c(1.33,-1.23,23.4343,-3000))

format_decimal <- function(x, digits=2){
  s <- stringr::str_split(as.character(x), "\\.", simplify=TRUE)
  mchar <- apply(nchar(s), 2, max)
  sprintf(paste0("%", mchar[1]+digits, ".", digits, "f"), x)
}
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), format_decimal))
```

When you print the data frame (outside of stargazer), you see that the values are left-aligned (which makes them decimal aligned when you print a fixed number of decimal places).

```
df
#          x
# 1     1.33
# 2    -1.23
# 3    23.43
# 4 -3000.00
```

However, when you use the same data in stargazer, the data are now centered.

```
stargazer(df, type = "text", 
          title            = "Align me plz",
          rownames         = FALSE,
          colnames         = FALSE,
          summary          = FALSE
)

# Align me plz
# ========
#   1.33  
#  -1.23    
#  23.43  
# -3000.00
# --------
```

So, it looks like the internals of the function trim and pad the values so they are centered.  To solve the problem, you would likely have to fiddle with the internals of the package.  There is a function that gets defined in there called `.trim` which shaves off leading and trailing spaces.  I tried to re-define that as `.trim = function(x)x`, but that didn't solve the problem either.  So it might be that changing that in coordination with changing something else or changing something else entirely is required.