# Error installing sdsMirco: Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path

Tags: r

I need to work with the [sdcMicro](https://sdcpractice.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sdcMicro.html) package.

I start by simply trying to include it:

```
> library(sdcMicro)
```

which gives me `

> there is no package called ‘sdcMicro

I try installing it:

```
> install.packages("sdcMicro")
```

Which runs for a really long time, and provides me with a output that I can't really decipher what means:

```
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘curl’
* removing ‘/home/ask/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/curl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘curl’ is not available for package ‘rio’
* removing ‘/home/ask/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/rio’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rio’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘rio’ is not available for package ‘car’
* removing ‘/home/ask/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/car’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘car’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘car’ is not available for package ‘VIM’
* removing ‘/home/ask/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/VIM’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘VIM’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘car’, ‘VIM’ are not available for package ‘sdcMicro’
* removing ‘/home/ask/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/sdcMicro’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘sdcMicro’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpBP1CoD/downloaded_packages’
```

It seems a little ambiguous, a bunch of dependencies failed, but package is installed.

Let's check, I run `library(sdcMicro)` and `require(sdcMicro)`.
Which fails in the same way as before.

I now look around a bit on the [documentation](https://sdcpractice.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sdcMicro.html). here it says that I should try running `update.packages()` and try again. I do this, and try again, which has no effect.

In the documentation, it also says that dependencies will automatically be installed with the package, so maybe that is not my issue?

How can I get this package?

**EDIT**

I now tried installing the failing dependencies ("car","rio","curl") one by one. The exact same thing still is happening

**EDIT 2**

As requested, here is the isntallation of dependencies:

First curl:

```
> install.packages("curl")
Installing package into ‘/home/ask/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/curl_4.3.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 793345 bytes (774 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 774 KB

* installing *source* package ‘curl’ ...
** package ‘curl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libcurl' found
Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libcurl' found
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
Using PKG_LIBS=-lcurl
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris)
If libcurl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘curl’
* removing ‘/home/ask/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/curl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpUpG4q8/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: try install.package("curl") since its the first poit of failure.

Comment: justr added an edit :)

Comment: (1) For your use of both `library` and `require`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51263513/3358272. Bottom line here, never use `require(.)` without checking and using its return value. (2) Please try `install.package("curl")` and *include all of its output in your question* (starting from `install.packages` and ending when your prompt returns). I understand there is stuff that you may not completely understand, but often the key component we need is tucked into that output.

Comment: cool, there uis an edit added with it

Comment: OK you need to install `libcurl` - make sure to post the full error message next time :). Are you on macOS / linux / windows?

Comment: will do :) Im on linux/ubuntu 20

Comment: hm, running `install.packages("libcurl")` gives me `package ‘libcurl’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3)`

Comment: It's not an R library, it's a set of linux headers that you install via the command line.

Comment: Try ``sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev``