# R return FALSE when NA when using == operator

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

i have an `if` loop than needs a logical check.

However the check is x==2

so that

```
> x<-2
> x==2
[1] TRUE
```

However when

```
> x<-NA
> x==2
[1] NA
```

How can I deal with this problem? I use this check within a `for` loop and the loop stops executing. When `x<-NA`, then `x==2` should return `FALSE`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)** First ensure that x is not NA and then AND that with the desired check.  If x were NA then it reduces to FALSE & NA and that equals FALSE.

```
x <- c(1, NA, 2) # test input

(!is.na(x)) & x == 2
## [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

**2)** If x is a scalar then this also works because isTRUE(X) is only TRUE if the argument is TRUE and if it is anything else including NA it is FALSE.

```
x <- 2
isTRUE(x == 2)
## [1] TRUE

x <- 0
isTRUE(x == 2)
## [1] FALSE

x <- NA
isTRUE(x == 2)
## [1] FALSE
```

**2a)** or if x is not necessarily a scalar we can modify it like this

```
x <- c(1, NA, 2) # test input
sapply(x == 2, isTRUE)
## [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

**2b)** or

```
x <- c(1, NA, 2) # test input
Vectorize(isTRUE)(x == 2)
## [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try:

```r
x <- 2
ifelse(is.na(x), FALSE, x == 2)
#> [1] TRUE

x <- NA
ifelse(is.na(x), FALSE, x == 2)
#> [1] FALSE
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `F` when you mean `FALSE`.  It will bite you some day!  E.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70499993/2554330 .

Comment: Thanks, @user2554330, for warning me! I am taking your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Use `%in%` instead of `==` which may fix this problem.

```
x <- 2
x %in% 2
#[1] TRUE

x <- NA
x %in% 2
#[1] FALSE
```