# Julia equivalent of R's `require()` function

Tags: r, function, julia

I am starting to write some Julia functions that rely on other packages for their computations. For example, in `R`, I will write the following if my function depends on the `dplyr` package.

```
foo <- function(x){
  require(dplyr) # the body part will use the package `dplyr`
  #body
}
```

What's the equivalent in Julia and, are they any best practices/suggestions when it comes to that? By now I am using `using Pkg` inside the body of the functions, but I am not sure about it. Thank you.

Comment: Since you ask about best practices, I'd mention that currently in R, the widely accepted best practice is [always use `library()`, never use `require()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51263513/903061).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for `using`. You can either `using` an entire package

```
using LinearAlgebra
```

or you can specify a list of just the specific things you want to use

```
using StasBase: fit, Histogram
```

There is also `import` but that is mostly used either
(A) when you want to include a file, rather than a package or

(B) when you want to *extend* a function from another package (including Base, if you want!) for, e.g., your custom types.

```
struct Point{T}
    x::T
    y::T
end

import Base.+
function +(a::Point, b::Point)
    return Point(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y)
end
```

```
julia> Point(3,5) + Point(5,7)
Point{Int64}(8, 12)
```

But unless you want to do that, you probably just need `using`.

The major difference is that you would not normally put your `using` statement within a function (rather put it at top level instead). Depending on code from another package *only within a single function* would arguably be a bit un-Julian.

Comment: I think this isn't 100% the same, see the discussion on `require` here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595512/what-is-the-difference-between-require-and-library - but depends on what functionality OP actually wants

Comment: Yeah, the use inside a function is definitely different. It may be a paradigm that doesn't really have an exact parallel in Julia

Comment: You can optionally precompile the package that you've just added. Some packages open much quicker if they have been precompiled. The 'plots' package is much improved by precompiling.