# R: How can I clean a dataframe column to remove unwanted characters and separate multiple values?

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I want to clean a column of an R dataframe that contains a mixture of values:

| chromosome_count |
| --- |
| 26 |
| 54 |
| c.36 |
| 28-30 |
| 12, 24 |

so that it looks like this, with comma separated values split into two rows and keeping only the minimum values where a range is recorded:

| chromosome_count |
| --- |
| 26 |
| 54 |
| 36 |
| 28 |
| 12 |
| 24 |

I'm a very stumped beginner and any advice would be very appreciated.

Comment: is your data really just one column?

Comment: No that's just one column of the dataframe! Apologies

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions. ie remove from the string the `-30` ie use a look behind, and if its a number, delete the end part of the range. This solution assumes the range is ordered `min-max`. Also delete anything from the start of a line that is not a digit

```
df %>%
  mutate(chromosome_count = str_remove(chromosome_count, "(?<=\\d)-\\d+|^\\D+")) %>%
  separate_rows(chromosome_count, convert = TRUE)

# A tibble: 6 x 1
  chromosome_count
             <int>
1               26
2               54
3               36
4               28
5               12
6               24
```

Answer (score -1):

```
require(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  chromo = c(26, 
             54, 
             "c.36", 
             "28-30", 
             "12, 24")
) 

df %>% 
  mutate(chromo = chromo %>%
           str_replace_all("(?<=-).*", "")) %>% 
  separate_rows(chromo, convert = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(chromo = chromo %>%
           str_replace_all("[^0-9]", "") %>% 
           parse_number()) %>% 
  drop_na()

# A tibble: 6 x 1
  chromo
   <dbl>
1     26
2     54
3     36
4     28
5     12
6     24
```

Comment: require/library: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51263513/3358272, https://yihui.org/en/2014/07/library-vs-require/, https://r-pkgs.org/namespace.html#search-path

Comment: The question asks that with a range (`28-30`), only the first/min value should be retained.