# table generated with data.table in R not printable on console

Tags: r, xcode, data.table

I generated a data table

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(
ID =c("b","b","b","a","a","c"),
a= 1:6,
b= 7:12,
c=13:18)
DT
```

The DT is shown in Environment. But print(DT) does not give an result in the console and class(DT) does not respond.
View(DT) shows the generated table. Same is with a data table downloaded from the internet.
I checked R-Studio and could not find any wrong settings.

Comment: Can you try on a fresh R session

Comment: Just a guess, but don't use `require`, use `library` instead. If `require(data.table)` does not find the package, it just returns `FALSE` which does not look bad or alarming. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51263513/3358272, https://yihui.org/en/2014/07/library-vs-require/, https://r-pkgs.org/namespace.html#search-path

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure can you try this from setting.

[image]

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but what in the question suggests the OP is attempting to render a notebook?