# R subset data.table by condition , getting nearest value row if missing

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to subset a data.table by condition "Year". Basically I want the data from the dt that matches a given year, per group. However, some groups do not have a complete time line across all years, and therefore I would like to return the nearest year's data for every group, so there are data for every group present for any year chosen (whether that is exactly the right year, or not).

```
library(data.table)

# make dummy data
dt <- data.table(Group = c(rep("A", 5),rep("B", 3),rep("C", 5),rep("D", 2)), 
x = sample(1:10,15, rep=T), Year = c(2011:2015, 2013:2015, 2011:2015, 2014:2015))

# subset by, e.g., Year == 2015 is fine, but I want a full result for ANY
# year chosen, such as 2012, by using the closest entry in time, per group. 

# Attempt;

y <- 2012

dt[Year == which.min(abs(Year - y)), .SD, by = Group]

Empty data.table (0 rows and 3 cols): Group,x,Year
```

The result in this example should be;

```
   Group x Year
1:     A 4 2012
2:     B 7 2013
3:     C 2 2012
4:     D 3 2014
```

Comment: How to break ties? E.g., what if you search for 2012 and there is 2011 and 2013 present. Which year should the be returned?

Comment: let's, for now, work on the premise that there are only years available in the future, i.e. timeline go back and stop, and do not restart

Comment: Hello, `which.min` returns an index. Do: `dt[, .SD[which.min(abs(Year - y))], by = Group]`

Comment: Two things: (1) don't use `require` this way: either use `library` or check the return-value from `require`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51263513/3358272, https://yihui.org/en/2014/07/library-vs-require/, https://r-pkgs.org/namespace.html#search-path. (2) Code blocks in the Stack interface use code fences `\`\`\`` as you used, but they must be on lines by themselves, shared with nothing. See my edits: the first code-fence `\`\`\`require(.)` _hid_ that expression, since Stack thought it to be a language-hint (no language named "require"), it is often `\`\`\`r` for R-based questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close: the use of `which.min(abs(Year - y))` is good, but needs to be within the `.SD`-subsetting in the `j` portion.

```r
dt[, .SD[which.min(abs(Year - y)),], Group]
#     Group     x  Year
#    <char> <int> <int>
# 1:      A     5  2012
# 2:      B     4  2013
# 3:      C     8  2012
# 4:      D     5  2014
```

---

Reproducible data

```r
set.seed(42)
dt <- data.table(Group = c(rep("A", 5),rep("B", 3),rep("C", 5),rep("D", 2)), x = sample(1:10,15, rep=T), Year = c(2011:2015, 2013:2015, 2011:2015, 2014:2015))
dt
#      Group     x  Year
#     <char> <int> <int>
#  1:      A     1  2011
#  2:      A     5  2012
#  3:      A     1  2013
#  4:      A     9  2014
#  5:      A    10  2015
#  6:      B     4  2013
#  7:      B     2  2014
#  8:      B    10  2015
#  9:      C     1  2011
# 10:      C     8  2012
# 11:      C     7  2013
# 12:      C     4  2014
# 13:      C     9  2015
# 14:      D     5  2014
# 15:      D     4  2015
y <- 2012
```

Comment: amazing! and thanks, yes so close. It's an index return. I shall accept when the timer allows me to.