# Access R code block in multiple instances

Tags: r, try-catch

I have a code block, to perform 3 times retry of the code execution in case of a specific error. In below example if HTTP 503 error occurred during the data download from ADLS container, I want the same operation to be executed maximum of 3 times retry.

```
require(AzureStor)
require(stringr)
recheck <- 0
while (recheck < 3){
  recheck <- recheck + 1
  tryCatch({
    storage_download(container, file, filename, overwrite=TRUE)
    recheck <- 4  
  }, error = function(e){
    if ( sum(str_detect(e, '503')*1) > 0 ){
      print(e)
      print(paste0('An infra-level failure occured. Retry sequence number is : ', recheck))
    } else{
      recheck <<- 4
      print(e)
    }
  }
  )
}
```

This code works fine for me, but similar to `storage_download` in the above example, I have other ADLS operations like `delete_blob`, `upload_blob`, `storage_upload`, `list_storage_files` at multiple instances in the code, I have to write above mentioned code for each of these functions. I want to make the above code as a function which can be called during each of these ADLS operations. Any thoughts or suggestions would help me greatly.

Comment: [Regarding your use of `require`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51263513/1968)

Comment: And what is the logic of `sum(str_detect(e, '503')*1) > 0`? You can just write `str_detect(e, '503')`.

Comment: I have some error code words in a vector. I want the if condition to work only on presence of any of the vector item. To simply the question I have just mentioned HTTP 503 error here in the example.

Comment: Hmm the `e` argument in the `tryCatch` `error` callback should only ever be a single error object. In fact, the code should use `conditionMessage(e)` instead of just `e`, my bad. — But even if `e` is a *vector*, your code is needlessly convoluted. Instead, use: `any(str_detect(e, '503'))`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph's answer below will solve this particular issue, but for a general approach that you could use in future projects it's worth having a read of this: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/function-factories.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
with_retries_on_failure = function (expr, retries = 3L) {
    expr = substitute(expr)

    for (try in seq_len(retries)) {
        tryCatch(
            return(eval.parent(expr)),
            error = \(e) {
                if (str_detect(conditionMessage(e), '503')) stop(e)
                message('An infra-level failure occurred. Retry sequence number is: ', try)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Used as follows:

```
with_retries_on_failure(storage_download(container, file, filename, overwrite=TRUE))
```

Note the `return()` call, which immediately returns from the surrounding function without the need to update the loop variable. Likewise, in the case of a failure we *also* don’t have to update the loop variable since we are using a `for` loop, and we use `stop()` to break out of the loop for any error that is not a 503 HTTP response.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help.  I believe I'm missing some dependencies in my R-studio. I'm getting code errors with `{` and `:`

Comment: @Konard Rudolph, That's a beautiful code block you have given. I have R vesrion 4.1.2, unfortunately I'm still getting same errors. I ll ask my IT team to upgrade to latest version of R.

Comment: @msr_003 Ugh, apologies, I just noticed a typo in the code. `:` should be `in`, obviously.

Comment: This is so perfect, just had to remove `!` in if condition to meet my need. Thank you!!