# Error when working on a corpus: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, corpus, quanteda

My plan is to work on a corpus of data in R, using the Quanteda package. I'm using the poliblogs.csv database accessible [from here](https://github.com/dondealban/learning-stm/blob/master/data/poliblogs2008.csv), with the script below. In the past, the script worked smoothly, but now an error message appears. The errors happen when I try to get the stats of the corpus or when I try to trim it.

The script I run is the following:

```
require("quanteda")
require("readtext")
require("topicmodels")
require("stm")
blog.dat <- readtext("poliblogs2008.csv",
        textfield="documents")

meta.list <- list(blog=blog.dat$blog,       
        day=blog.dat$day,
        rating= blog.dat$rating)
names(meta.list)
blogcorpus <- corpus(blog.dat,
            meta=meta.list)
meta <- meta(blogcorpus)
mycorpus.stats <- summary(blogcorpus)
blog.dfm <- dfm(blogcorpus, remove=stopwords("english"),
                stem= TRUE,
                removePunct= TRUE)
```

The errors appear when I run the lines:

```
mycorpus.stats <- summary(blogcorpus)
```

and

```
blog.dfm <- dfm(blogcorpus, remove=stopwords("english"),
                stem= TRUE,
                removePunct= TRUE)
```

In both cases, the following same error message appears:

```
Error in if (...length() && any(...names() == "Dimnames")) .Object@Dimnames <- fixupDN(.Object@Dimnames) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

The same error appears with a multiplicity of datasets, so it doesn't seem to be data-dependent.

UPDATE: Actually, the problem was caused by a bug that occurred to RStudio itself. Uninstalling and re-installing R and RStudio solved the issue and made the error disappear. Thanks to everyone who looked and provided a solution.

Comment: FYI, you are using `require` incorrectly, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51263513/3358272, https://yihui.org/en/2014/07/library-vs-require/, https://r-pkgs.org/namespace.html#search-path. For what you're doing, use `library`, not `require`.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification on the point, that I incorporated. Unfortunately, this doesn't change the error in discussion.

Answer (score 1):

`require(quanteda)` is fine, but you should update the packages.

```
> blog.dfm <- dfm(blogcorpus, remove=stopwords("english"),
+                 stem= TRUE,
+                 removePunct= TRUE)
Warning messages:
1: 'dfm.corpus()' is deprecated. Use 'tokens()' first. 
2: removePunct argument is not used. 
3: removePunct argument is not used. 
4: 'remove' is deprecated; use dfm_remove() instead 
5: 'stem' is deprecated; use dfm_wordstem() instead
```

It should be

```
> blog.toks <- tokens(blogcorpus, remove_punct = TRUE) %>% 
+     tokens_remove(stopwords("en")) %>% 
+     tokens_wordstem()
> blog.dfm <- dfm(blog.toks)
> blog.dfm
Document-feature matrix of: 13,246 documents, 102,320 features (99.83% sparse) and 5 docvars.
                     features
docs                  week fals statement lie dismiss apolog pakistani presid pervez musharraf
  poliblogs2008.csv.1    2    1         2   1       1      1         1      1      1         7
  poliblogs2008.csv.2    1    0         0   0       0      0         0      0      0         0
  poliblogs2008.csv.3    0    0         0   0       0      0         0      0      0         0
  poliblogs2008.csv.4    0    0         0   0       0      0         0      0      0         0
  poliblogs2008.csv.5    0    0         0   1       0      0         0      0      0         0
  poliblogs2008.csv.6    0    0         0   0       0      0         0      2      0         0
[ reached max_ndoc ... 13,240 more documents, reached max_nfeat ... 102,310 more features ]
```

Comment: `require` might *work* but, as explained in the posted links, it’s *not* “perfectly fine”.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the update to the package. Actually, in the end I discovered that the error was caused by a strange bug in RStudio. Uninstalling and reinstalling R and RStudio solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. Uninstalling and reinstalling R fixed it for me as well. Un/Reinstalling RStudio was not necessary.