# Error in file(file, "r") : cannot open the connection

Tags: r

I have been trying to run this code and nothing is working but it did work a while ago. I do not know what I am doing wrong. I also combined a data set and this is the code I put(I do not know which is the issue)

The error I keep getting is on the line of "fit_CFA_groups", and it states

```
Error in file(file, "r") : cannot open the connection
3.
file(file, "r")
2.
scan(file = file, what = "", sep = ";", strip.white = TRUE, comment.char = "#")
1.
cfa(three_factor_groups, data = df3, group = "country")
```

This is the code I have put in

```
library(haven) #packages 
library(dplyr)
library(vctrs)

library(haven)
NewIrishdata <- read_sav("NewIrishdata.sav")


df3 <- bind_rows(Englishdark, NewIrishdata)
df3
```

```
library(haven)
require(semTools)
library(semTools)
library(psych)
library(readr)
require(sem)
library(sem)
three_factor_groups <- 
              'General =~ Machiavellianism1 + Machiavellianism2 + Machiavellianism3 + Machiavellianism4 + Machiavellianism5 + Machiavellianism6 + Machiavellianism7 + Machiavellianism8 + Machiavellianism9
 + Narcissism1 + Narcissism2 + Narcissism3 + Narcissism4 + Narcissism5 + Narcissism6 + Narcissism7 + Narcissism8 + Narcissism9 + Psychopathy1 + Psychopathy2 + Psychopathy3 + Psychopathy4 + Psychopathy5 + Psychopathy6 + Psychopathy7 + Psychopathy8 + Psychopathy9'
fit_CFA_groups<-cfa(three_factor_groups, data= df3, group="country")
summary(fit_CFA_groups)

require(semPlot)
library(semPlot)
require(qgraph)
semPaths(fit_CFA_groups, layout='circle',style = "lisrel",what="std", combineGroups = F)
```

Comment: Are those datasets in the working directory.  The code didn't show how you created the `Englishdark`

Comment: I put                                                                                                                
```#downloading data
library(haven)
Englishdark <- read_sav("C:/Users/megan/Downloads/Englishdark.sav")
View(Englishdark) #view data```

Comment: The error suggests that your path may be incorrect.  Please use `file.path`

Comment: Hiya! How exactly would I use file.path(). What would I put in the ().

Comment: When formatting code in StackOverflow code blocks, the triple-backticks `\`\`\`` must go on their own line with no code before or after them. On the first (entering) code fence, there _may_ be a language-hint such as `lang-r`, but it is not required, and whether or not it is recognized, it is never displayed. This means that any code that is on the same line as the opening backtick-fence is hidden from readers. Next time you ask a question, please just keep them on their own lines, as in `\n\`\`\`\n`. Cheers.

Comment: You should almost always use `library`, not `require`. The latter never stops following code when the package is not available, which is almost never what is intended. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51263513