# error while looping through dbexecute command in R

Tags: sql, r, database, sqlite, for-loop

I am trying to loop through dbexceute command in r while processing my mode file to remove element by element and store them in a separate file for each element. But while running the loop I am getting an error in R.

```
 library("RSQLite")
 sqlite <- dbDriver("SQLite")
 dbname <- "models_signif.db" 
 db = dbConnect(sqlite,dbname)
 brain_n <- dbGetQuery(db,"SELECT * FROM weights")
 x <- which(brain_n$gene %in% "ENSG00000130943.6")
 rsid_list <- brain_n$rsid[x]
 ##now loop for generating the files
 for( i in 1:128){
   #copy original file db to another
   #use that for modifications: 
   library("RSQLite")
   sqlite <- dbDriver("SQLite")
   dbname <- "models_signif.db" 
   db = dbConnect(sqlite,dbname)
   #brain_cortex_gtex_n <- dbGetQuery(db,"SELECT * FROM weights")
   require("RSQLite")
   sqlite <- dbDriver("SQLite")
   myfile <- paste0("modelsn","_",i,".db")
   dbname1 <- myfile
   db1 = dbConnect(sqlite,dbname1)
   sqliteCopyDatabase(db, db1)
   dbDisconnect(db)
   #gtex_n_1 <- dbGetQuery(db1,"SELECT * FROM weights") ##dim 9453
   ##now filter row1098 its beta is 0.002 and rsid is rs4560235
   #dbGetQuery(db,"SELECT * FROM weights") ##dim 5415rows
   rsid <- rsid_list[i]
   dbExecute(db1,"DELETE FROM weights WHERE rsid=rsid_list[i] ") 
   dbDisconnect(db1)
 }

Error: 
Error: near "[i]": syntax error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rdis_list[i]` is R code, not SQL code. The SQLite engine (or any DBMS engine) is not going to interpret it the same. And since it is in a string in R, the R parser is not going to try to infer that it should be replaced with something.

The quick/hasty (and not best-practices) approach would be to `paste` it into your query. Again, **not the recommended approach**.

```r
   dbExecute(db1,paste("DELETE FROM weights WHERE rsid=",
                       dbQuoteLiteral(db1, rsid_list[i])))
```

The better approach is to use "parameter binding", for several reasons. Use `?` each place you are putting in "data"-like things in your query, and add `params=list(..)` to the query/statement.

```r
    dbExecute(db1,"DELETE FROM weights WHERE rsid=?",
              params = list(rsid_list[i]))
```

See [parameterized queries](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries) for more details about using bound-parameters like this.

Some side notes:

1. You define `sqlite`, `dbname`, and `db` outside the loop, it is wasteful, unnecessary, and helping not-at-all to recreate those variables each pass in the loop. The variables are accessible from within `for`, use them.
2. Don't use `require` there, for two reasons. First, you've already loaded `library("RSQLite")`, so the package functions are already available in your environment, so doing `require` is doing absolutely nothing but wasting (micro)time. Second, only use `require(.)` (for any use) if you believe that the package may not be available, you capture its return value, and react differently on its results. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51263513/3358272, https://yihui.org/en/2014/07/library-vs-require/, and for details about the related functions, https://r-pkgs.org/namespace.html#search-path.

Comment: Thank you everyone for providing feedback. i will remove require and move sqlite,dbname and db inside the loop