# How to find the value of x for first derivative

Tags: r, loops, derivative

I have these following parameters and function :

```
require(plot3D)
require(numDeriv)
require(rgl)


Mass.init<-8.8
k<-8.617333262*10^(-5)

r_tref.d<-0.300 
e.d<-0.4 
eh.d<-3 
th.d<-31 
tref.d<-20


TPC.dev<-function(x){
  r_tref.d*exp((-e.d/k)*(1/(x+273.15)-1/(tref.d+273.15)))/
    (1+exp((eh.d/k)*(1/(th.d+273.15)-1/(x+273.15))))}
```

I want to find the x value for which the first derivative is equal to 0. I tried to make a loop :

```
Mean.vector <- seq(10, 30, 0.01)



tolerance <- 1e-6
x_values <- numeric()


for (i in 1:length(Mean.vector)) {
    x <- Mean.vector[i]
    deriv.dev <- genD(TPC.dev, x)

    if (all(abs(deriv.dev$D[, 1]) < tolerance)) {  # Vérifiez la dérivée par rapport à la deuxième colonne
      x_values <- c(x_values, x)
    }
  }


print(x_values)
```

But when I run the code, I obtain this :

```
> print(x_values)
numeric(0)
```

But visually, it should be around 25. Do you know how I can find that ?

Comment: What is `genD`?

Comment: [A word on `require` vs. `library` …](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51263513/1968)

Answer (score 0):

Your code only checks the three values in `Mean.vector` and none of them is close enough to the function's peak so you get no result. Instead, you can use optimization:

```r
# Function whose minimum will be searched for
f_opt <- function(x) {
  abs(genD(TPC.dev, x)$D[, 1])
}

# searches where f_opt() is minimized between 10 and 30
opt <- optimize(f_opt, c(10, 30))
opt$minimum
# [1] 26.10623
```

You just have to be careful about the searched interval as  `optimize()` is not guaranteed to find the global minimum. When I tried to search the interval [0, 30], the algorithm reported a minimum value at the local minimum at (almost) zero.

Answer (score 0):

I would first derive the derivative symbolically, e.g. with the **cOde** package, and then use `uniroot`.

```r
library(cOde)

# symbolic derivative
fn <- 
  "r_tref.d*exp((-e.d/k)*(1/(x+273.15)-1/(tref.d+273.15)))/(1+exp((eh.d/k)*(1/(th.d+273.15)-1/(x+273.15))))"
jacobianSymb(c(x = fn))
# "-(r_tref.d*(exp((-e.d/k)*(1/(x+273.15)-1/(tref.d+273.15)))*((-e.d/k)*(1/(x+273.15)^2)))/(1+exp((eh.d/k)*(1/(th.d+273.15)-1/(x+273.15))))+r_tref.d*exp((-e.d/k)*(1/(x+273.15)-1/(tref.d+273.15)))*(exp((eh.d/k)*(1/(th.d+273.15)-1/(x+273.15)))*((eh.d/k)*(1/(x+273.15)^2)))/(1+exp((eh.d/k)*(1/(th.d+273.15)-1/(x+273.15))))^2)" 

k<-8.617333262 * 10^(-5)
r_tref.d <- 0.300 
e.d <- 0.4 
eh.d <- 3 
th.d <- 31 
tref.d <- 20

f <- function(x) {
  -(r_tref.d*(exp((-e.d/k)*(1/(x+273.15)-1/(tref.d+273.15)))*((-e.d/k)*(1/(x+273.15)^2)))/(1+exp((eh.d/k)*(1/(th.d+273.15)-1/(x+273.15))))+r_tref.d*exp((-e.d/k)*(1/(x+273.15)-1/(tref.d+273.15)))*(exp((eh.d/k)*(1/(th.d+273.15)-1/(x+273.15)))*((eh.d/k)*(1/(x+273.15)^2)))/(1+exp((eh.d/k)*(1/(th.d+273.15)-1/(x+273.15))))^2)
}

# plot to locate the zero
curve(f, from = 10, to = 30)
abline(h = 0, lty = "dashed")
# the zero is attained for x approx 26

# now use uniroot
ur <- uniroot(f, lower = 25, upper = 27)

# the root 
ur$root
# 26.10624
```

Or using **Ryacas**:

```r
library(Ryacas)
# set values of parameters
yac_str("{k, rtrefd, ed, ehd, thd, trefd} := {8.617333262e-5, 0.3, 0.4, 3, 31, 20}")
# define f
yac_str("f := rtrefd*Exp((-ed/k)*(1/(x+273.15)-1/(trefd+273.15)))/(1+Exp((ehd/k)*(1/(thd+273.15)-1/(x+273.15))))")
# solve df/dx = 0
yac_str("Newton(D(x)f, x, 26, 0.000001, 25, 27)")
# "26.1062405404"
```

Or using **giacR**:

```r
library(giacR)
giac <- Giac$new()
giac$execute("k := 8.617333262e-5")
giac$execute("rtrefd := 0.3")
giac$execute("ed := 0.4")
giac$execute("ehd := 3")
giac$execute("thd := 31")
giac$execute("trefd := 20")
giac$execute("f := rtrefd*exp((-ed/k)*(1/(x+273.15)-1/(trefd+273.15)))/(1+exp((ehd/k)*(1/(thd+273.15)-1/(x+273.15))))")
giac$execute("df := function_diff(f)")
giac$execute("newton(df(x), x, 26)")
# "26.1062405417"
giac$close()
```