# could not find function "." when run from Rmd

Tags: r, data.table, r-markdown

The following part of the code is working when run directly from Rstudio, but is not working from R package when it is inside of the Rmd chunk:

```
coverage <- reads[, .(coverage = fiber::coverage(.SD, ref_seq_length)$coverage,
                      bin_position = fiber::coverage(.SD, ref_seq_length)$bin_position),
                  by = .(sample_name, ref_seq_name)]
```

> Error in .(coverage = fiber::coverage(.SD, ref_seq_length)$coverage,
> bin_position = fiber::coverage(.SD,  :    could not find function "."
> Calls:  ... eval_with_user_handlers -> eval -> eval -> [ ->
> [.data.table -> [.data.frame

I was trying to reinstall 'data.table' as following:

```
unloadNamespace('fiber')
unloadNamespace('data.table')
unloadNamespace('reshape2')
unloadNamespace('plyr')

install.packages("data.table", type="source", dependencies=TRUE)
```

Wrote "`require(data.table)`" before and in the first chunk.
also `require(data.table`) was added to the `fiber::coverage` function.

data.table was added in DESCRIPTION Depends: R (>= 4.0.0): data.table, ...

Rmarkdown Cash was always removed.

Reads are 'data.table'. Moreover another code using data.table is working:

````
```{r test-plot}
library(ggplot2)
options(bitmapType='cairo')
dt <- data.table(x=c(1,2,3,4,5),
           y=c(1,2,3,4,5))
ggplot(data=dt, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```
````

Removing problematic part into a separate function and calling it from the chunk does not solve the problem. The new function is perfectly working from Rstudio on the same computer, but not from the rmarkdown report.

Comment: Typo? It's `require(data.table)`.

Comment: No idea where the error comes from, but perhaps try using `list()` instead of `.()`?

Comment: Use `library(data.table)`. Never use just `require(data.table)` unless you are checking its return value and acting on it if `FALSE`. (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51263513/3358272, https://yihui.org/en/2014/07/library-vs-require/, https://r-pkgs.org/namespace.html#search-path.)

Comment: Please clarify if you actually wrote `require(data.tables)` which is a typo, or if you wrote `require(data.table)` and mistyped it in the question.

Comment: sorry for the typo. `require(data.table)` was used. `library(data.table)` as well.
Updating R to the last version and updating all packages solved the problem. It works now. It also works with `list()` instead of `.()` as was suggested. Thank all of you for the ideas and support.