# Why subsetting a data.table using a key deletes the key if key values are not pre-sorted?

Tags: r, data.table

Here's my code:

```
require(data.table)

data("USArrests")
dt1 <- as.data.table(USArrests, keep.rownames = T)
dt1[, state:=rn]
setkey(dt1, state)

key(dt1)
# "state"

states1 <- c('Iowa','Ohio','Utah')
states2 <- c('Utah','Iowa','Ohio')

dt.subset1 <- dt1[states1]
dt.subset1 # 3 rows as expected
key(dt.subset1) # "state", as expected
# "state"

dt.subset2 <- dt1[states2]
dt.subset2 # 3 rows as expected
key(dt.subset2) # NULL - why?
# NULL

dt.subset2a <- dt1[sort(states2)]
dt.subset2a # 3 rows as expected
key(dt.subset2a)
# state
```

Both `dt1[states1]` and `dt1[states2]` return correct subsets as expected, but only the first one keeps the key column while second one has it reset. It seems the key is conserved only if values are pre-ordered - but is it expected/documented behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of `states1` affects the order of the data. Notably, the returned rows are in the order of the states in your vector, which is likely desired.

However, the way that `data.table` does keys, as soon as the key field internally is no longer sorted (since the `key(.)` operation reorders the rows internally), it un-sets the key in the data.

So long as the order of `states` is in the same order within the keyed table, then, the returned data will retain the key. I recognize it this example is trivial enough, but in your real data if you create `states2` such that the order of values are in the same order as within the keyed table -- alphabetical in this case -- then the returned table should keep its key.

For reference, https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-keys-fast-subset.html

Comment: yes now I understand that keeping the key is incompatible with keeping the order of the provided key values. But then I think it would make sense to be more consistent and _always_ drop the key so that the developer knows they must take care of it...

Comment: Actually, my opinion ... return the ordered/keyed data _in the same order_ as the key mandates, instead of relying on the order of the keys being queried. That way, `dt1[states1]` and `dt1[rev(states1)]` return the same still-keyed object, and it would be up to the user to re-order, resulting in an intentional (vice _implied/inferred_) step of removing them silently. Meh. (Perhaps the default use of key-querying should be to use `dt1[(sort(states2))]`, which should work unless the internal sorting is different than `sort(.)`.

Comment: BTW, side note on your question-code: you should almost always use `library`, not `require`. The latter never stops following code when the package is not available, which is almost never what is intended. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51263513/3358272, https://yihui.org/en/2014/07/library-vs-require/, https://r-pkgs.org/namespace.html#search-path @VasilyA

Comment: Thanks! I'll use the right one next time