# Error in reading .csv file when rendering pdf in Quarto - Duplicate key values

Tags: r, quarto

I'm currently trying to upload a .csv file onto Quarto to show a table of data. However, when I render the quarto file into PDF there's an error once it reaches the .csv line. The code was this:

```
#| warning: false
#| echo: false
require(data.table)
require(flextable)
fread("data/table.csv") |> flextable(cwidth = c(1, 1, 1, 4)) |> fontsize(size = 8)
```

It showed this error:

```
Error in `vecseq()`:
! Join results in 580 rows; more than 165 = nrow(x)+nrow(i). Check for 
duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x 
over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each 
group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to 
proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE. Otherwise, please search for 
this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and data.table 
issue tracker for advice.
```

My dataframe is made of lots of inner_joins / left_joins from `dplyr` package but I'm quite confused as to where it went wrong!

I tried to add `allow.cartesian = TRUE` after in the code with inner/left joins but no luck.

I just want to show the dataframe onto the quarto PDF export.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Nikki Yu! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly randomly), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Side note: you should almost always use `library`, not `require`. The latter never stops following code when the package is not available, which is almost never what is intended. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51263513/3358272, https://yihui.org/en/2014/07/library-vs-require/, https://r-pkgs.org/namespace.html#search-path

Comment: For sample data in this case, perhaps a better way to share it would be to [edit] your question and paste the top so-many-lines (10? 20? Just enough to be able to reproduce the error, no more) into a [code block]. Thanks!