# Error with polr function in R: initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression

I checked all the questions related to this problem. I found one solution, including changing the start parameters. However, it did not work either.

I am trying to run the ordered logit model for regression analysis. I have one dependent and 18 independent variables (each is different (binary, ordered, number)). I wrote the following code in R but I cannot continue:

```
require(foreign)
require(ggplot2)
require(MASS)
require(Hmisc)
require(reshape2)

file_path <- "C:/Users/NISA/Desktop/ordered_logit_model_main_.xlsx" 
dat <- read_excel(file_path)

head(dat)
str(dat)
summary(dat)


m <- polr(as.factor(purchase_tendency) ~ education + experience + age + 
        familiarity + purchase_decision_present + price 
      + range + charging_time + charging_type + maintenance_cost + 
        number_of_battery + repair_costs + second_hand_value + 
        environmental_impact + charging_stations + future_features + 
        tax_reduction_policy + other_provided_policies, data = dat, Hess=TRUE, method="logistic")

summary(m)

(ctable <- coef(summary(m)))

p <- pnorm(abs(ctable[, "t value"]), lower.tail = FALSE) * 2

(ctable <- cbind(ctable, "p value" = p))


(ci <- confint(m)) 


exp(coef(m))


exp(cbind(OR = coef(m), ci))
```

It gives the following error:
Error in optim(s0, fmin, gmin, method = "BFGS", ...) :
initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite
In addition: Warning message:
glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

What would be the other solutions to this error? I am a newbie in R so I appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Comment: (1) Use `library`, not `require`, you're using it wrong here; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51263513/3358272. (2) `head(dat)` and `str(dat)` and `summary(dat)` might help _you_, but not only do we not have `dat` (or any idea what it looks like), including these expressions does not help the situation. Please make this question reproducible by reading https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 , [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.