In R renv package: do I need to call library()?
One question:
Eerytime a start a project in R that use the renv package/structure, is it possible to call all the packages from the lock file using library function?
Or do I have to call all the packages from lockfile writing in the code using library(package1),library(package2), library(package3), library(package4) and so on?
In other words I have something like renv::library(all packages from lockfile)?:
And then starting my project?

This should load all libraries in your lockfile:
lapply(names(renv::lockfile_read()$Packages), library, character.only = TRUE)

But in reality, not all libraries need explicit library() calls as some are just dependencies of others.
So if you prefer, you can also add to the .Rprofile of your project the libraries that needs to be loaded. It is a file that is run automatically every time you start R in that project.
Hope that helps!

Thanks a lot! One question: I still need to call  library() function somewhere in my code, right? I thought that using renv() package/environment In wouldnt need to do this beacause somehow the project would run all the library() function for all the packgae in the lock file

Renv creates an environment for each of your Rprojects. It means that it helps with installing/saving information about the R packages in the correct version for this project. Installing a package and loading it are two different things, and renv does not deal with loading the packages with the function library(). So indeed, the line of code that I shared should be put inside of your script.
Also note that require() is an alternative to library(), if that was the issue in understanding my answer.

If for some reason you do not want to load the packages inside of your script, you can do the loading of the packages in the .Rprofile file that should already exist in your Rproject directory. As I said, it is a file that is run automatically every time you start R in that project.

Amazing, @vgilbart. Thanks for your time!  Last question: do you follow some good practice regarding the library/require packages functions?

require() tries to load the package. It won't raise an error if the loading fails, but will siply return FALSE. Whereas library() will fail.
You can take a look at the discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595512/what-is-the-difference-between-require-and-library and the blog post there https://yihui.org/en/2014/07/library-vs-require/
In this case, library() should be more suitable, I'll edit my original answer!
